# Can a component have its own state?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

Whenever I use Frameworks such as React , Vue or anything else. I see that every value (input value, select value ...) is always being emitted through events to parent. I don't really get why this is good. It takes more ressources / time to pass it to the parent component. Why doesn't the component handle its data by itself?? Why should every single value inside a child component get passed to the state of the parent to make the handling of the data ?
For example, I generally see the loading of the APIs in the parent and then the values of the API get passed down through props or Redux/Vuex. Why can't we get the API values inside the child directly when it's being mounted instead of having to pass it down on many levels or through the local store

Comment: Yes, a component *usually* has its own state - in Vue, the data() function or variables in the Vue3 setup() function. Only information important to parent/child components is passed along via events or properties.

Comment: I have  a question, lets suppose you have a tags component that contains label tags like this. https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fvuejs-tips%2Fvue-js-tip-5-tag-list-component-ccd0f9ca1f5a&psig=AOvVaw3eFwYtfi2aw4TV6MoUmsGL&ust=1647868573841000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCJjx7Pri1PYCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD

Does this component fill its data() with an array that contains all of the tags or should that be handled by the parent component?

Comment: The parent component likely needs the array of tags, yes. If it was an auto-complete list, though, the parent wouldn't need the value of the auto-complete input field, or the list of tags that match the user's input, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to have a state inside reusable component, especially if it holds users input. You can still provide it with callbacks in props, which respond to onChange, onBlur or other events based on your needs, or you can communicate with your reusable component via refs, which is fairly flexible way to get user input.

The important thing is, that the reusable component should be as much independent on it's environment as possible. If you don't provide it with a state, the component (in case of your Pickers) will be dependent on props passed down from its parent expressing it's current user input on every rerender and on callbacks updating its current input somewhere higher in component hierarchy on every change, which is not what you want in every case, and it already forces you to make relatively large adjustments in you parent component, which misses the point of reusability.